# AndroidX recyclerview 1.0.0 vs 1.1.0 issues

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I recently updated recyclerview 1.0.0 to 1.1.0

Everything seemed to work fine but now Im getting some rare crash reports that views are null

now I managed to reproduce it in a bottom sheet with a recyclerview inside

```
 @BindView(R.id.earningTitleTextView)
    TextView earningTitleTextView;

    @BindView(R.id.earningAmountTextView)
    TextView earningAmountTextView;


public KeEarningItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.context = itemView.getContext();
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public void setContent(KeEarnings.KeEarningItem earningItem){
        if(earningTitleTextView != null){
            earningTitleTextView.setText(earningItem.getTitle());
        }
        if(earningAmountTextView != null){
            earningAmountTextView.setText(earningItem.getValue());
        }
    }
```

setContent is called in the onBindViewholder method
but it seems that the binding happens before the viewHolder is completely created?!
earningTitleTextView and earningAmountTextView are both null

Was there anything completely changed how to handle Viewholder that I missed or is there just a bug in the new Recyclerview 1.1.0 ?

Comment: added recyclerview 1.0.0 again and everything works fine once more ie the viewholders are created first and then onBind is called after this is done...

Comment: Was it something similar to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145941830

Comment: I would say no, this seems more about the underlying data structure not being correctly reflected by the adapter/recycler view while for me it seems more like binding being performed before the inflating is finished.